# ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException during IDLE task in Spring Integration Mail

Tags: spring-integration, jakarta-mail, imap

I am trying to fetch emails from an email server with Spring-Integration-Mail, and below is the kind of trace that I get.

From the program's behavior point of view I noticed that messages are successfully retrieved only on the initial run of the program, and after that it looks like it does not get any new emails, probably because IDLE task fails?

Anyway, `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException` seems weird to me. I only can tell that INBOX contained 6 messages at the time when this script ran, however there are other folders with messages in them.

Any ideas?

```
2016-09-22 08:29:01,792 [task-scheduler-1] DEBUG o.s.i.m.ImapIdleChannelAdapter - waiting for mail
2016-09-22 08:29:02,138 [task-scheduler-1] DEBUG o.s.i.m.ImapMailReceiver - This email server does not support RECENT or USER flags. System flag 'Flag.FLAGGED' will be used to prevent duplicates     during email fetch.
2016-09-22 08:29:02,375 [task-scheduler-1] WARN  o.s.i.m.ImapIdleChannelAdapter - Failed to execute IDLE task. Will attempt to resubmit in 10000 milliseconds.
java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: message number (7) out of bounds (6)
    at com.sun.mail.imap.MessageCache.getMessage(MessageCache.java:135)
    at com.sun.mail.imap.MessageCache.getMessageBySeqnum(MessageCache.java:164)
    at com.sun.mail.imap.IMAPFolder.getMessageBySeqNumber(IMAPFolder.java:3005)
    at com.sun.mail.imap.IMAPFolder.search(IMAPFolder.java:1863)
    at org.springframework.integration.mail.ImapMailReceiver.searchForNewMessages(ImapMailReceiver.java:202)
    at org.springframework.integration.mail.ImapMailReceiver.waitForNewMessages(ImapMailReceiver.java:167)
    at org.springframework.integration.mail.ImapIdleChannelAdapter$IdleTask.run(ImapIdleChannelAdapter.java:220)
    at org.springframework.integration.mail.ImapIdleChannelAdapter$ReceivingTask.run(ImapIdleChannelAdapter.java:190)
    at org.springframework.scheduling.support.DelegatingErrorHandlingRunnable.run(DelegatingErrorHandlingRunnable.java:54)
    at org.springframework.scheduling.concurrent.ReschedulingRunnable.run(ReschedulingRunnable.java:81)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.access$201(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:180)
    at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:293)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
2016-09-22 08:29:12,376 [task-scheduler-1] DEBUG o.s.i.m.ImapIdleChannelAdapter - waiting for mail
2016-09-22 08:29:12,739 [task-scheduler-1] DEBUG o.s.i.m.ImapMailReceiver - This email server does not support RECENT or USER flags. System flag 'Flag.FLAGGED' will be used to prevent duplicates     during email fetch.
2016-09-22 08:29:12,970 [task-scheduler-1] WARN  o.s.i.m.ImapIdleChannelAdapter - Failed to execute IDLE task. Will attempt to resubmit in 10000 milliseconds.
java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: message number (7) out of bounds (6)
    at com.sun.mail.imap.MessageCache.getMessage(MessageCache.java:135)
    at com.sun.mail.imap.MessageCache.getMessageBySeqnum(MessageCache.java:164)
    at com.sun.mail.imap.IMAPFolder.getMessageBySeqNumber(IMAPFolder.java:3005)
    at com.sun.mail.imap.IMAPFolder.search(IMAPFolder.java:1863)
    at org.springframework.integration.mail.ImapMailReceiver.searchForNewMessages(ImapMailReceiver.java:202)
    at org.springframework.integration.mail.ImapMailReceiver.waitForNewMessages(ImapMailReceiver.java:167)
    at org.springframework.integration.mail.ImapIdleChannelAdapter$IdleTask.run(ImapIdleChannelAdapter.java:220)
    at org.springframework.integration.mail.ImapIdleChannelAdapter$ReceivingTask.run(ImapIdleChannelAdapter.java:190)
    at org.springframework.scheduling.support.DelegatingErrorHandlingRunnable.run(DelegatingErrorHandlingRunnable.java:54)
    at org.springframework.scheduling.concurrent.ReschedulingRunnable.run(ReschedulingRunnable.java:81)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.access$201(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:180)
    at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:293)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

**Update**

It looks like this may have to deal with deleted messages not bean purged from the INBOX. When I checked the INBOX from my desktop mail client, it was showing 6 messages in the inbox, however when I logged into the mail via the webmail, it was showing 6 usual emails, and 1 crossed over with a line, and an annotation their was saying that there are 7 messages in the INBOX, 1 of which is deleted. Once I moved that email from INBOX, the new messages that was not processed previously got retrieved by spring-mail-integration.

The question is, is there a way to alter this behavior via spring-mail-integration settings, e.g. ignore deleted but not purged mails?

Comment: This looks like a problem with the javamail library - all Spring is doing is a `searchForNewMessges`. What version of javamail are you using? The current version used by the latest Spring Integration is 1.5.5.

Comment: If you're using Exchange, you may be running into an Exchange server bug that has a workaround in the latest versions of JavaMail.  The most recent version is [1.5.6](https://java.net/projects/javamail/pages/Home).

Comment: Thanks for the answers! I updated the version of javax.mail I was specifying in my `build.gradle` from 1.4.7 to 1.5.6 (sun's) and now I stopped getting index out of bound exception, but instead I am getting `DEBUG IMAP: ignoring message number 5 outside range 4` in mail debug output. So it looks like it stopped throwing however the problem itself did not go away - I am still not receiving anything if there are deleted (but not purged) messages in folder.